# Documentation on how to use REST WebAPI like a boss

Tags: wcf, rest, asp.net-web-api, documentation

I've exposed a few methods and, while crystal clear on how they're supposed to be used, I'm sure that with time, the memory will fade and I'll be standing there like an idiot wonder why on Earth I haven't provided any help.

When we use WCF, there's the WSDL file. But I'm not aware of any corresponding functionality for WebAPI. Usually I add a *Ping* so that I can type in the URL window of my browser *.../Service.svc/Ping*, just to see that I a date back.

What would be an intuitive and (hopefully fairly) canonical approach? I'm thinking *.../Help*. Is there a better way?

Just pushing out help will only produce a huge string (XML or JSON formatted), which isn't very like-a-boss'y. Anonymous types can't be well handled without serialization. pushing out *object* typed entity breaks the connection.

I wish to have a built-in documentation on how to use the calls. The names themselves, of course, but also what values are treated (I had a case where the *.../Donkey?scope={scope}* pattern could be *null* or *all* and we though it was *any*, which took a while to figure out.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might checkout [`Swashbuckle`](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) which would allow you to generate [`Swagger`](http://swagger.io/) documentation for your ASP.NET Web API controllers.

> Anonymous types can't be well handled without serialization. pushing
>   out object typed entity breaks the connection

Are you really exposing anything like the above mentioned in your Web API contracts. I hope you don't.

Comment: Oh, that's quite good. However, if possible, I'd like it to be built-in so that e.g. the different values that are going to be treated also are documented. Those can't be automatically discovered by a software. Nevertheless, threat link as is.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what do you mean by *different values* that need to be documented. Ideally your ASP.NET Web API exposes REST methods that have request/response models. An automatic tool such as Swagger in this case could perfectly fine cover them.

Comment: No, I'm not. Except for the documentation. But it's probably not going to happen, neither. Nothing else's exposed that way. +1 for the heads up in case I was.   :)

Comment: Well, if a field is called *amount* it's obvious what to send. But if it's called *scope*? It could be (strings): *none*, *any* but also *zero*, *some*, *all*.

Comment: `Swashbuckle` will inspect the view models that your Web API controller actions take and return. Then it will generate proper documentation for each of the types. Also it absolutely doesn't matter how your Web API controller action argument is named. From a consumer perspective what matters is what properties does it have. How are they named and what types do they have. That's what a consumer needs to know, and that's what Swashbuckle will do when generating the Swagger documentation based on the metadata.